# Good way to handle sessions in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, session, model-view-controller

I was wondering if there is a better way to handle handling sessions than running this set of code through each one of my controller methods.

```
public ModelAndView addUser(@RequestParam("userid") String userId,
        @RequestParam("passwd") String passwd,
        @RequestParam("usrtype") String usrtype,
        HttpSession session,
        Model model ){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    if ((String) session.getAttribute("userId") == null) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Session was terminated.");
        model.addAttribute("url", "/login");
        mav.setViewName("redirect");            
        return mav;
    }
...
```

How would one go about making this into reusable code?

Comment: If you want to roll your own security layer use a `HandlerInterceptor` which will be applied to all handlers (in this case the controller). If you want a full blown solution and not roll your own use Spring Security.

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to optimize this:

- Securing requests is something [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) is made for. Spring Security uses a Servlet filter to intercept (and deny) requests before they arrive in your controller. So you do not have to handle security related code in controller actions
- If, for whatever reason, you can/want not use Spring Security you should have a look at Spring's [MVC interceptions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). In interceptors you can place code that need to be executed before and after controller actions.
- If you always need to set the same Model attribute you can annotate methods with `@ModelAttribute`. This method will then be called for every request to populate your model, see [ModelAttribute methods documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods). [ControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) is similar, it is used if other classes than the controller should provide model information.